# Computer restarts without warning; code bcc116

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, cpu, reboot, overheating

Processor: Intel i5 4430 4-Core 4x3Ghz
Motherboard: msi h87-g41
Graphics Card: Nvidia GTX760
Power supply: eps-750 cm
RAM: 8GB

I bought a new assembled gaming PC which worked fine for a few days. Then it started rebooting without warning. After it restarts windows 7 gives me an bbc 116 error code. Apparently it's something to do with my video card, either it overheating or wrong drivers. I've installed the latest driver from Nvidia for my graphics card. Since it's brand new it can't be dust, I'm running it with its lid open to see if the problem persists. I'm also running prime95 now to see if it tells me anything else. Using core temp it tells me that my CPU reaches up to 95° celsius with the blend stress test from prime95. Aaaand it just peaked to 100°. Of course it doesn't reach these temperatures at all while idle/gaming.

I'm gonna let prime95 run for a night and to see what happens. Until then does anyone know what I should do next?

I didn't buy it from a nearby shop, I ordered it online from another country, so I'd like to fix it myself if it's simply software related.

UPDATE1:

Prime95 ran for about ten hours, the CPU never going above 100°. It crashed again when I put the lid back on. It didn't restart this time, the screen just went black. Again I got the same code after I rebooted. Also ran the furmark GPU stress test for 15 minutes, temperatures maxed out at 75°. Also ran sfc.exe /scannow in the cmd, no problems there. Used [this suggested link](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us) and applied the fixit.

I have the three minidumps if anyone wants to take a look at them. No idea how to add them though.

UPDATE 2:

My computer has been fine for the past 4 days now. I assume the link I mentioned solved my problem by increasing the timeout detection through the registry.

Comment: think its more of a driver/hardware kinda issue rather then temp - could be wrong though. since its new, might be worth bringing it back to your dealer and replicating the issue for them to observe.

Comment: `Since it's brand new it can't be dust` ... Since it's brand new, take it back to the shop!! Get them to fix it! Why fix something which could damage the warranty etc?

Comment: I googled the error code and everyone seems to agree the problem is due to GPU overheating. You might want to check out these [two](http://www.sevenforums.com/crash-lockup-debug-how/63320-stop-0x116-video_tdr_error-troubleshooting.html) [links](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have directx installed by any chance do you?  I have been doing a bit of googling over the issue you describe in your question and the two same fixes seem to appear all over the place (MS Answers, seven forums, toms hardware etc).  The two answers seem to be:

Uninstall/reinstall the latest directx version.  The problem seems to be related to memory corruption when loading/unloading large video sections in gaming.

Update/reinstall your nvidia drivers.  There are a lot of people who reported that they started having this issue right after updating nvidia drivers, but the reports are slightly older and there arent any complaints that I've seenwhich relate to the latest driver batch.

Also, try a system restore to a known date when things were working... not mentioned online, but always a good first point of call.

You mentioned that your PC was brand new.  If you bought it from a shop - can you not take it back for repair/replacement?  If it was a home build, have you checked all your cabling, slot insertion etc?  Unlikely to be the problem, but again - always good practise.

Hope this helps.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

> I bought a new assembled gaming PC which worked fine for a few days. Then it started rebooting without warning. After it restarts windows 7 gives me an bbc 116 error code. Apparently it's something to do with my video card, either it overheating or wrong drivers. I've installed the latest driver from Nvidia for my graphics card. Since it's brand new it can't be dust, ...

If it's brand new (yes, a few days old is brand new) and purchased assembled, I wouldn't bother trying to diagnose it unless there was a good reason to spend my time and possibly money on it. Just pick up the phone and call the place where you bought it, and tell them you are having these troubles with it and are **bringing it in to have them take a look at it.** If they are at all service-minded, they aren't going to have much of an issue with that, if any at all. *Make sure to tell them as much as you can about these problems,* including for example how long the computer appears to need to be powered on before it reboots, any software changes you have made since you got it, etc.

A few days of usage is certainly early enough that any problem this is an indication of was pre-existing at the time of purchase.

The only exception to this I can think of is if you have installed software which might reasonably be causing this behavior; you don't really say anything about that.

> I'm running it with its lid open to see if the problem persists.

Note that running the computer with the case open might actually *worsen* cooling problems. Cooling is about *airflow,* and opening the case changes the airflow dynamics. It also allows dust unobstructed into the computer interior, but for testing, that shouldn't be that great a concern. If your problem is a lack of cooling, what this boils down to is that it should simply make the problems manifest themselves sooner; it shouldn't cause any further notable damage.

For a somewhat extreme example to illustrate this point (the specifics will obviously depend on the intended airflow, fan placement, etc.), consider the CPU fan blowing fresh air onto the CPU chip and heatsink. In a closed-case setup, the air will be drawn into and expelled from the case by the case fans (exhaust fans may be replaced by simply overpressure within the case), providing airflow not only around the CPU but also over many other components as well. By opening the case, you allow for the air to "bounce" right back off the motherboard and exit the case. The same goes for the exhaust fan(s) in particular, which might be pulling air from the immediate vicinity of the fan, depriving other components of the intended airflow.

Comment: I didn't buy it from a nearby shop, I ordered it online from another country, so I'd like to fix it myself if it's simply software related. Prime95 ran for about ten hours, the CPU never going above 100°. As I tried to put the lid back on

Comment: @RobertC. Well, having ordered internationally would in many cases likely be a very valid reason for not wanting to just send it back to the place of purchase. However, that sort of restrictions on answers really should go into the question itself. Assuming you are signed in, you can always [edit your own question](http://superuser.com/posts/762477/edit) to add additional information; click "edit" below the question text.

Comment: Pressed enter by accident, couldn't edit it again. Here is the rest:

more info: 
Prime95 ran for about ten hours, the CPU never going above 100°. It crashed again when I put the lid back on. It didn't restart this time, the screen just went black. Again I got the same code after I rebooted. Also ran the furmark GPU stress test for 15 minutes, temperatures maxed out at 75°. Also did sfc.exe /scannow in the cmd, no problems there. Used this suggested link and applied the fixit https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665946/en-us.

Comment: @RobertC. Comments should be used to request clarification or suggest improvements on the post that is being commented on. If you wish to add additional information that would be useful in answering the question, please do so by editing the question, not by commenting on an existing answer. Thank you.